# Can I view resolved files after a merge in hg?

Tags: mercurial

I'm using mercurial and one problem I found while merging was the fact that it's hard for a single developer to merge with the default trunk after a lot of changes.

So even if the developer resolves the conflicts by hand there is always a change to miss some of the intersecting changes.

I would like to take a look at the history of a merge and see the resolved files, so other developers can review it.

Can I view resolved files after a merge in hg?

Comment: One way to mitigate this problem is to avoid getting "a lot of changes" in either branch between merges. In other words, don't postpone merging from the default branch to just before you intend to reintegrate the other branch back into default, but merge periodically, like every day. This way you get smaller conflicts, fewer conflicts, and less uncertainty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I like to do is this workflow:

```
hg pull
;; assuming I'm on development branch
hg merge -r default
hg diff  ;;do incoming changes look good
;; run tests 
hg commit -m "merged from others, lookin' good"
hg up default -C
hg merge -r development
hg diff   ;;everything look good still?
;; run tests
hg commit -m "And back to default, all tests pass"
hg push
```

Comment: ok, but what I say is , when you do hg merge -r default, and you have 100 files changed, 80 automatically merged and 20 with conflicts. I resolved the 20 and finish the merge but then I wish to see the list of those 20 that I manually fixed to give them to extra review.

Comment: What you can do is attempt a re-merge.  Just update to the commit before the merge and then do `hg merge`. You can then list the files that are in conflict using `hg resolve --list`.  After you've got your listing, get rid of your re-merge using `hg update -C`.  It's kind of a hack, but it should work, and you could always write a script to do it.

Comment: In order to "replay" the merge, you need to merge the two original heads. A simple `hg merge` won't do that. You need to update to one of the two heads, then execute `hg merge -r REV_OF_OTHER_HEAD`. When you do this, you'll re-execute the exact same merge that was done earlier. If you actually commit this, you'll end up with another head, with the same content, but a different timestamp and potentially a different name as the original commit of the original merge (provided you resolved everything the same way.)